# Query to count values from different tables

Tags: oracle

From a database composed of two tables, EMP and DEP, I need to list all locations (DEPT.LOC ),how many departments are in this location  and how many employees (EMP.EMPNO) are in this departments.

Create a view listing all locations (Loc) along with the number of departments in that location and the number of employees employed in those departments.

I wrote the below query but I get the error: missing expression.

```
SELECT D1.LOC, COUNT(D1.DEPTNO),COUNT(SELECT * FROM EMP E,DEPT D WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO AND  D.LOC = D1.LOC ) FROM DEPT D1 GROUP BY D1.LOC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you tried is almost right (although it is not the most natural way to do it) - and it can be salvaged.

Your inner `select` returns several rows per department. `COUNT(...)` applies to a single expression - it is over a column, but it counts individual expressions, not multi-row inputs.

Instead, in the inner select you should select `count(*)`, not `*`; and then the outer aggregate should be `sum()`. Something like this:

```
SELECT D1.LOC, COUNT(D1.DEPTNO),
       sum((SELECT count(*) FROM EMP E, DEPT D 
            WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO AND  D.LOC = D1.LOC ))
FROM DEPT D1 GROUP BY D1.LOC
```

Note also the two sets of parentheses used with the `sum()` function. (This is, in fact, what caused the immediate error you reported.) You are summing numbers, and the outer parentheses are part of the function call. But the numbers you are summing are the result of a "scalar subquery" (a subquery that returns a single row and single column, which happens to be a numeric value over which you can sum; in this case, that numeric value is a count, of employees by department). A subquery, scalar or otherwise, must always also be enclosed in its own set of parentheses, even if it appears within a function call, or other kinds of parentheses.

Now: the more natural way to do the same thing is with a join; not sure if you are far enough in your intro course to have studied this though.

```
select d.loc, count(distinct d.deptno) as departments, count(e.empno) as employees
from   dept d left outer join emp e on d.deptno = e.deptno
group  by d.loc
;
```

The *outer* join is needed so that departments are counted (for each location) even if they don't have any employees. In the `SCOTT` schema there is, in fact, a department with no employees - and it is the only department in its location. If you used an *inner* join above, that location wouldn't even appear in the output.

NOTE - the homework problem asks you to create a view, not a `SELECT` query. That part is trivial - I assume you can do it by yourself.